# HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error for idle Spring Boot Web Application com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a running Spring Boot web application hosted in Tomcat 9 configured with MySQL database which is running without any issues. When the application is deployed in live server and kept idle for at least 12 hours the issue starts arising. The error is as follows.

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
```

Root Cause is

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
    org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
```

And Root cause follows like this

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 221,081,546 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 221,081,546 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:953)
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1471)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2322)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2075)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2037)
    org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:956)
```

This problem arises only in live server and not in local dev environment when the application is kept idle for 12 hours. Doing a simple browser refresh solves the problem though.

I have set this

```
server.tomcat.keep-alive-timeout = -1
```

in **application.properties** but it has no effect.

Comment: As the last root cause suggests - `The last packet successfully received from the server was 221,081,546 milliseconds ago. ....., increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.`  Did you try to set `autoReconnect=true` in your JDBC URL?

Comment: Do you also have a `spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1`? This will be executed to keep the connection alive after some interval.

Comment: @Ishan I have not tried 'autoReconnect=true' since somewhere in stack overflow, I found it is not recommended thus it has some disadvantages. Though I am going to give it a try now finding no other way.

And I have no idea what does spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1 do?

Comment: `spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1` defines the SQL that is to be executed to determine if the connection is valid or not.  It is the simplest query possible. It should happen every few seconds/minutes. Also `spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true` should be set to make sure whenever an already open connection is returned to a thread from the free connection pool, it is tested to be still valid. So, the thread never gets any invalid connection.

Comment: On this page - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#appendix.application-properties.data - search for the term `spring.datasource.tomcat`. Those highlighted parameters have a few at the end like `spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-interval, spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query, spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query-timeout, spring.datasource.tomcat.validator-class-name`. Check those out.